# Different conditional checking ways

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

To check an `int` within range `[1, ∞)` or not, I can use the following ways (use #1, #2 a lot):

1. `if (a>=1)`
2. `if (a>0)`
3. `if (a>1 || a==1)`
4. `if (a==1 || a>1)`

Is there any difference that I should pay attention to among the four versions?

Comment: for an *int*, the only different ones are 3 and 4, because in 3 for example, a==1 will only be checked if a>1 was false, and the opposite is true for 4

Comment: As far as optimization goes, the first two will almost certainly generate identical instructions. However, I'm not so sure about the last 2. Because logical OR is required to short circuit evaluation of its operands, the compiler might be required to generate separate instructions for the 2 tests. Anyway, it's a micro-optimization; and don't do 3 & 4, from a stylistic perspective they look odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally there is no difference between the 4 ways you listed.  This is mainly an issue of style.  I would venture that #1 and #2 are the most common forms though, if I saw #3 or #4 on a code review I would suggest a change.

Perf wise I suppose it is possible that some compiler out there optimizes one better than the other.  But I **really** doubt it.  At best it would be a micro-optimization and nothing I would ever base my coding style on without direct profiler input

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why you would use 3 or 4. Apart from being longer to type, they will generate more code. Since in a `or` condition the second check is skipped if the first is true, there shouldn't be a performance hit except for version 4 if value is not 1 often(of course hardware with branch prediction will mostly negate that).

Answer (score 1):

```
1. if (a>=1)
2. if (a>0)
3. if (a>1 || a==1)
4. if (a==1 || a>1)
```

On x86, options 1 and 2 produce a `cmp` instruction. This will set various registers. The `cmp` is then followed by a condition branch/jump based on registers. For the first, it emits `bge`, for the second it emits `bgt`.

Option 3 and 4 - in theory - require two `cmp`s and two branches, but chances are the compiler will simply optimize them to be the same as 1.

You should generally choose whichever (a) follows the conventions in the code you are working on (b) use whichever most clearly expresses the algorithm you are implementing.

There are times when explicitly writing "if a is equal to one, or it has a value greater than 1", and in those times you should write `if (a == 1 || a > 1)`. But if you are just checking that a has a positive, non-zero, integer value, you should write `if (a > 0)`, since that is what that says.

If you find that such a case is a part of a performance bottleneck, you should inspect the assembly instructions and adjust accordingly - e.g. if you find you have two `cmp`s and branches, then write the code to use one compare and one branch.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! They all are the same for an `int`. However, I would prefer to use `if (a>0)`.

Comment: short circuit evaluation?

Comment: There is always short circuit evaluation in 3 and 4 but why make the code look bad?

Comment: i was just pointing out that they are not the same in general, obviously they look bad